# Nothing happend when clicking a button in selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/canada/')
time.sleep(1)
button = driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 5500)") 
button1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[8]/div/div[9]/a/button')
button1.click()
```

[image]

Trying to click this button using xpath but it just doesn't seem to click the button to extend the webpage. I first tried to copy by xpath which didn't work and then I copied the full xpath which also didn't work. After that, I tried to find by name and enter the text on the button and click the button. But none of these methods actually worked and clicked the button. So how can I click this button so that it extends the webpage allowing me to scrape more of the webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on `View more News` Induce `WebdriverWait` and wait for `presence_of_element_located()` and following **css** selector.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/canada/')
button=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a.load-more__btn>.btn")))
button.location_once_scrolled_into_view
button.click()
```

---

Or Use following **xpath**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/canada/')
button=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//a[@class='load-more__btn']/button[@class='btn']")))
button.location_once_scrolled_into_view
button.click()
```

Comment: works ty. Also could you explain to me why my method wasn't working and why this one works? I am very new to selenium so i would love to know

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the button wasn't at "clickable state" despite was rendered in page at moment.
To obviate this, you have to add an explicit wait to tell the driver to wait until it's state change to clickable.

Try to use this code instead :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC    

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/canada/')
time.sleep(1)
button = driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 5500)")
button1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[8]/div/div[9]/a/button')))
button1.click()
```

Comment: i didn't test the python code, please tell me if anything goes wrong.

Comment: "raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:" that is the error I get. The code works but the button is not pressed. That error message I think is caused by this line of code: ''button1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[8]/div/div[9]/a/button')))'"